# В чем разница SQLiteOpenHelper и SQLiteDatabase?

Tags: java, android

Начал пробовать работать с БД и вот такой вопрос получился)

Немного посерфил и насколько понял, то `SQLiteOpenHelper` расширяет `SQLiteDatabase`, но и чет там еще... Но поскольку всего час разбираюсь в этом, то решил узнать что для чего?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для работы вам скорее всего нужен будет именно `SQLiteOpenHelper` , т.к. `SQLiteDatabase` финальный класс. В классе который наследуется от `SQLiteOpenHelper` вы переопределите методы `onCreate()` и `onUpgrade()`.

В `onCreate()`  - вы создаете таблици в БД.
В `onUpgrade()` - вы можете изменить версию БД, если, например добавили новые модели в БД.

Ну это так... коротко!

Comment: Ну судя по примерам я понимаю, что в большинстве случаев используют именно `SQLiteOpenHelper` , но можно чуть развернутее чем просто два слова `финальный класс` )) Иии? Что я из этих 2 слов должен понять?))

Comment: SQLiteDatabase содержит в себе базовые методы: открытия, закрытия, удаления БД и т.д. , а  SQLiteOpenHelper - вспомогательный класс для создания и управления версиями БД. Это все)

Comment: Ладно буду читать))

Comment: К сожалению, это все что я смог по этой теме рассказать)